# jQuery-ui dialog custom buttons are keeping ui-state-active after click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to apply some styling to the buttons of a jQuery-ui dialog. What I'm experiencing is that after pressing one button down and move the mouse out of the button area (like dragging), the button will keep the ui-state-active class. How can I remove effectively the ui-state-focus and ui-state-active class for my buttons?

I'm doing this in the open event:

```
open: function(event, ui) { 
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', ui.dialog).hide(); 
    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button').removeClass().addClass('button white').on('mouseover', function() { 
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }).on('mouseup, mousedown, mouseenter, click', function() { 
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus ui-state-active'); 
            }); 
        }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/5mp437p4/4/) (click and drag the 'Yes' button first. then the symptoms will be also on the 'no' button)

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy all events on the buttons and apply your own. Something like this:

```
open: function(event, ui) { 
   $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', ui.dialog).hide(); 
   $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button').off().on({
       blur: function() {
          ..do what you want..
       },
       focus: function() {
          ..do what you want..
       },
       click: function() {
          ..do what you want..
       },
       etc.
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I distinguish both buttons in order to reassign each one the respective functionality and css styles?